# How do I change the maptype in ggmap?

Tags: r, ggmap, terrain

I am having trouble changing the background of my `ggmap`. When I try to change the `maptype` it always comes out as `terrain`. I would like to change it to `satellite`. Any suggestions? Here is my code:

```
 library(ggmap)
 # Long and Lat Coordinates
 Cuba_all <- data.frame("Longitude" = c(-79.79623, -79.42313, -79.01722, -80.29218, -80.50040, -80.51981, -80.36674, -79.87957, -79.66906, -79.76122, -80.26587, -79.91689, -80.10454, -80.22530, -80.12910, -79.98889, -79.84307, -79.81694, -80.22201, -80.48088, -80.44482, -80.29068, -80.36213, -80.50879, -80.29634), "Latitude" = c(22.06622, 22.14845, 22.20900, 22.05258, 22.30107, 22.88154, 22.70679, 22.53541, 22.39237, 22.35697, 21.91868, 22.08949, 21.83760, 22.10561, 22.11061, 22.02766, 22.04936, 22.37516, 22.56684, 22.44313, 22.44416, 22.50470, 22.75872, 22.35473, 22.49178))
 # Create Cuba Dimensions
 sbbox <- make_bbox(lon = Cuba_all$Longitude, lat = Cuba_all$Latitude, f = .1)
 sbbox
 # Grab Map of Cuba
 sq_map <- get_map(location = sbbox, source = "google", maptype = "satellite")
 # Plot Map
 ggmap(sq_map)
```

Comment: Look at the 'maptype' of your result. I'm guessing that you didn't supply a proper key to the Google server and the `get_map` function therefore defaulted to a "stamen" map which doesn't have a "satellite" option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@42's comment is partly right (as far as I can tell). But it's not necessarily your API key that's the problem, it's your location specification. The Google map server wants location specified as lon/lat at the *center*, plus a zoom factor. `get_map()` **silently** decides to get a Stamen terrain map if you submit the location in bounding box format; this appears to me to be a bug (or "infelicity") in `get_map()`, and is the subject of at least [two](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/287) [issues](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/281) on the `ggmap` issues list.

In any case, when I specified the right lon/lat vector, and played around with the zoom factor until it's about right (I don't know how to do this other than trial and error ...), it worked for me.

```
sm <- with(Cuba_all,c(lon=median(Longitude),lat=median(Latitude)))
sq_map1 <- get_map(location = sm, zoom=9,
                   source = "google", maptype = "satellite")
ggmap(sq_map1)+
    geom_point(data=Cuba_all,aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude),colour="red")
ggsave("cuba.png")
```

[image]

---

A little more digging in `get_map()` makes it look like this may have been an oversight by the developers. It seems to have been fixed in the development version of `ggmap`, but hasn't made it to the CRAN version yet (see comments [here](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/287).)

This code chunk:

```
if (is.numeric(location) && length(location) == 4) {
    location_type <- "bbox"
    location_stop <- FALSE
    source <- "stamen"
    maptype <- "terrain"
    ## ...
```

detects that the location has been given as a bounding box and automatically sets source to "stamen" and maptype to "terrain".  Later on there's code that looks like it should give a warning if you pass a bounding box with `source=="google"`, but it can't ever be reached (because source will have been changed to "stamen" by this point) ...

```
if (source == "google") {
    if (location_type == "bbox") {
        warning("bounding box given to google - spatial extent only approximate.", 
            call. = FALSE, immediate. = TRUE)
        message("converting bounding box to center/zoom specification. (experimental)")
        user_bbox <- location
        location <- c(lon = mean(location[c("left", "right")]), 
            lat = mean(location[c("bottom", "top")]))
    }
```